# An unknown Error in a website created with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Do you know the reason or the method that cause this Error :

Open /path1/path2/ : invalid argument

It is response of a request , and response code is 500 (internal server error ) with above message.

The website use Ruby on rails and I think that error is related to ruby on rails code but I don't know what methods (maybe Open in Io )

Comment: Unfortunately we'd need more information than that in order to help. If you have a more extensive error message, that would help. If you look in the log files of the application, you should be able to see a more complete error message

Comment: @Jad it is not my website, I'm a bug hunter and I'm trying to find the reason of that And after injecting Null byte, the server returned error 500  with that error message.

Comment: Hopefully, someone with access can get you those logs? Do you have access to the source code?